# why ajax modal takes too much time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello stackoverflow users,

I have a jquery to open a modal and the code is as follow

```
$(".openVarifiedModal").click(function(){

    var otpFor = $(this).data("value");
    var formdata = $(this).data("fieldvalue");

    $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:'ajax/ajax_send_otp.php',
      data:{
        otpFor:otpFor,
        dataw:formdata
      },
      success: function(data){
         alert(data);
      }                
  });
});
```

And The PHP Page is

```
include("../include/database.php");

if($_REQUEST['otpFor'] == "cmobile" || $_REQUEST['otpFor'] == "cmobile2"){
    $cmobile = $_POST['dataw'];;
    $cemail = "";
}else{
    $cmobile = "";
    $cemail = $_REQUEST['dataw'];
}

$otp_type = 3;
$todate = date('Y-m-d');
$otp = "451".rand(1,9);

// $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO `user_otp`(`date`,`cmobile`,`email`,`otp`,`otp_type`) VALUES ('$todate','$cmobile','$cemail','$otp','otp_type')");
// QUery Takes Only 0.0580 To execute.

if($result){
    echo "OK";
}else{
    echo "NOT OK";
}
```

After Success Modal Takes 3.0 Seconds to open a modal after insert. i also tried to insert a second modal it will opens immediately.

But here twist is when i removes *`include('database.php')`* it will opens immediately. And my database php have nothing expect database connection

This is Network Tab Firefox After Clicking
[image]
*`I have Lots Of Jqyery Code in My Page(e.g. 500+ Lines Functions)`*

Comment: Are you using 2 database connections?

Comment: Nope Only one database but i use two methods one is MySQL and another is MySQLii

Comment: Why you are doing this? Use only mysqli

Comment: Because in some module of my app i use mysqli

Comment: Use only mysqli that is better than mysql. There are not requirement of using both

Answer (score 0):

Got response in milliseconds to show popup after complete ajax. Have structure as you have above
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CLzI.png)

Comment: I also knows that. but the question is why i am getting 2.5 - 3 second to open modal..

Comment: After ajax complete?

Comment: May it take time to append data in popup.

Comment: i dont append anuything

Answer (score 0):

no data delivered by ajax php file. because you don't choose right object in jquery script. 
comment or explain your goal of this lines:

```
var otpFor = $(this).data("value");
var formdata = $(this).data("fieldvalue");
```

Comment: `var mydata = $("#hidden_otp_number").val();//GETS OTP NUMBER
      var otpFor = $("#hidden_otp_for").val();//GETS OTP IS FOR means (mobile or email)`

Comment: how do you fill values of these hidden elements?

Comment: By using php method

Answer (score -1):

in firefox , use firebug (F12) and Network tab to monitor duration of each transaction with server. 
maybe it's because of some other resources...

 a screenshot of firebug Netwrokr tab help to answer better than this.

updated...

maybe it's because of GET type of your ajax. You call POST method in php part but use GET in ajax!

updated...

please send your php codes to test locally...

Comment: Question Updated ...!

Comment: change ajax method to POST

Comment: first i tried with post method. that didn't work. so i used get method :-(

Comment: use mysqli and see network tab of firebug again. maybe it will show error on the post transaction. you can use php debugs logs too.

Comment: Check Whole Code Here....https://eval.in/962863. Included PHP + HTML + AJX REQUEST